# is it ok to store executables in programdata?

Tags: windows, security, uac

is it ok to store executables in programdata or appdata? 
The result is that i can modify it (update it) without having to display the uac warning, but on the other hand so can any other application..

Note: It seems that google chrome is doing this.

Comment: And why are you so afraid of the UAC message?

Comment: i was more or less just wondering if its ok to do so, as chrome does it? (and i think click once does so to) or if its against the rules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The major advantage is that users without admin access can install software without admin permission.
The major disadvantage is that users without admin access can install software without admin permission.

Comment: Users have *always* been able to install software without admin permission; that's what group policy was invented for in the first place. I don't understand people that are complaining about this.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is becoming more common to see apps installed in these locations (chrome, runonce, gtalk) - it is a security risk, and as [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12050367/573083) said - the benefit is also it's largest downside.

Many enterprises are now blocking apps from running from these locations.  As more and more enterprises identify this as a gaping security hole, I'd expect more and more organizations to lock this down.

I think that your question: `"Is it against the rules"` is a subjective one.  There is certainly room for debate, but it ultimately seems like a proactive decision to circumvent the intended security of the system.  I personally would not install to these locations.

Answer (score 2):

`%APPDATA%` is a reasonable location, in the event the application is truly intended for use by a single user. In this case, it is not a security risk. By default, only the user in question has access to their `%APPDATA%` folder, so there is no crossing of a trust boundary happening here.

`%PROGRAMDATA%` is less reasonable. First of all, this directory was added in Vista, so that might be a problem. However, if you're installing here, you are installing to a location which is systemwide. User A might install your program, but user B has access to that location. Thus, user B might overwrite your program with something malicious, tricking user A into running it. This is a security risk.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but any program running under the same user can modify %APPDATA%? so a virus could replace it or modify it?

Comment: @Petoj: Yes, but the same can be said for petty much every other directory. If you can install there, that means the user has write and execute access to that location. If they have write access to that location, they can replace your binaries. There's no way around that, whether you use program files or appdata. In Windows (and most other security systems), the identity is the user, not the application.

Comment: @Petoj: Related http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/18/705957.aspx